# Uninstall an specific version of PostgreSQL

Tags: apt, postgresql

I have Postgresql 9.1.1 in my Ubuntu 12.04 which got installed due to automatic upgrades and whenever I uninstall it using the command:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql-9.1.1
```

I get an error saying:

```
E: Unable to locate package postgresql-9.1.1
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'postgresql-9.1.1
```

Can somebody tell me how to uninstall this package completely so that I can install the other lower version - 8.4.7

Comment: The second part of your question (downgrading) is answered where you've asked it: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285232/how-do-i-downgrade-postgresql

Answer (score 29):

The version 9.1.1 of PostgerSQL is located in the package `postgresql-9.1`. So you should remove this package:

```
sudo apt-get purge postgresql-9.1
```

The second part of your question is already answered here: [How do I downgrade PostgreSQL?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285232/how-do-i-downgrade-postgresql)

Answer (score 13):

If you want to uninstall postgresql and any related package, you should use `autoremove`:

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove postgresql*
```

This will select any package starting with postgresql and remove any automatic dependency that these packages installed efectivelly removing any version of postgresql. If you only want to remove the client or the server, your bet should be on `apt-cache search postgresql | grep client` or `server`.

Comment: `zsh: no matches found: postgresql*`

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql-9.1
```

Also you can install 8.4.7 and stop the server postgresql-9.1.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql
```

Answer (score 0):

I fear the package locations will differ form version to version, so you can uninstall the most from your OS with

```
sudo apt-get purge postgresql-9.1
```

but then you will have to find all remaining files and directory with

```
sudo updatedb && locate *postgres*9*
```

and remove them manually with

```
sudo rm -rf <pattern>
```

---

For example, I can tell that for postgres 14.7 you should run these commands

```
sudo apt-get purge postgresql-14.7

sudo rm /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-14-main.log
sudo rm -rf /run/postgresql/14*
sudo rm -rf /run/systemd/generator/postgresql.service.wants/postgresql@14-main.service
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/postgresql/14/
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/doc/postgresql-14*
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/doc/postgresql-client-14*
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/lintian/overrides/postgresql-14
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/lintian/overrides/postgresql-client-14
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/postgresql/14/
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/postgresql-common/t/140_pg_config.t
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/info/postgresql-14*
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/info/postgresql-client-14*
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/postgresql/14/
```

in the end, check the results with

```
psql --version
```